# C# ListView images not showing at runtime

Tags: c#, image, listview, imagelist

Hello I've made a simple ListView which has 2 columins, it's a Detail ListView, i've created an ImageList and added my images inside, I set the column ImageIndex(I've tried with ImageKey also) for both of my columns and Images show inside designer but once I run the program there is no images being shown.

Here is a screenshot of designer [image: http://i.imgur.com/ZohRUon.png]

Comment: do you mean displaying an icon?

Comment: Well image at column name... http://i.imgur.com/ZohRUon.png

Comment: Is 'Clear()' called somewhere? Or are the images absent but column contents is still shown?

Comment: Clear() isn't called, yes, column images are absent but contents are still being drawn.

Answer (score 6):

This is a flaw in the designer, it doesn't properly serialize the `ColumnHeader.ImageIndex` property.  You'll for example see that the image is gone again when you close the designer window and re-open it.

The KB article that @Idle linked is much too heavy-handed, you simply need to do the same thing you did in the designer.  Setting the ImageIndex again.  Do so in the form constructor.  I can't tell what the correct code might be from the screen-shot but it ought to resemble:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.Columns[0].ImageIndex = 0;
        listView1.Columns[1].ImageIndex = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Much easier Hans, thanks!  I just took the MS article at face value and didn't try to work out any other solutions.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I just ran into this bug myself. Amazing that the MS guys STILL haven't fixed this in Visual Studio 2K15!

Answer (score 2):

Despite showing the icons in the column header at design-time, apparently the ListView control in .Net doesn't actually support this feature:

> This behavior occurs because the .NET implementation of the
>   System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader class does not include the
>   capability to assign an image to the ColumnHeader control. You can
>   assign only text to a ColumnHeader control.

The code in [PRB: Cannot Assign Images to a ColumnHeader Control in a Windows Forms ListView Control in Visual C# .NET](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/314933/en-us) worked fine for me, however.

After adding the code and running my test app, my column headers had the same icon in them at run-time that was assigned to them at design-time.